# Error passing through catch block powershell

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to check for the file path for firefox in Windows x64 Host Key. It has a try catch block that has a fully qualified error id in the brackets.

Despite the error message being the same that is in the code, it does not catch the error.

```
 $program = "FireFox"

 $filepath = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

 $FPF = $filepath + "\" + $program 

 try { Get-ChildItem $FPF} 

     catch [PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand] {

         if ($_.Exception.Message -match "Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path*") {

             Write-Host "false"}
     }
```

The full error that comes out is

`Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\FireFox' because it does not exist.
At line:7 char:7
+ try { Get-ChildItem $FPF}
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...install\FireFox:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

What could could be the issue?

Comment: Does your registry path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\FireFox really exist?

Comment: No it does not. Ultimately, I am going to put this on a script that will install Firefox after that check is done

Comment: There is a difference between a terminating error (what `try` is for) and a non terminating error (what `get-childitem` it doing). either way you should be using `if(Test-Path $FPF)` for things like this.

Comment: Oh I see. I am going to test that out now

Comment: That seemed to do it. `Test-Path` must have been what I needed to do originally. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can **bypass the need for your attempt at exception handling by using the [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) cmdlet up front to determine whether a given path exists** - and if the *existence* is all you care about, that is enough: `if (Test-Path $FPF) { ... }`

*Generally speaking*, however, even if the path *exists*, you may still run into errors on *traversal*.

---

To address your original attempt: there are two fundamental problems:

- As [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) points out in a comment, **`Get-ChildItem` not finding a given path results in a *non-terminating* error, whereas `try` / `catch` only applies to *terminating* errors**.

  - You can, however, *promote* non-terminating errors to terminating ones, by adding common parameter `-ErrorAction Stop` to the command.
  - For a summary of PowerShell's error types and their handling, see [this GitHub post](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).
- **To qualify conditional `catch` handlers, you must use *exception-type literals*, e.g., `[System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]`**, *not* the value of an error record's `.FullyQualifiedErrorId` property (e.g., `PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`)

  - To determine the full name of an error record's exception type, run the following after the error occurred:

    - `$Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName`

---

Here's an amended version of your code, based on the above:

```
try {
    Get-ChildItem $FPF -ErrorAction Stop
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] { # input path not found
    Write-Error "Not found: $FPF"
} catch {  # any other error
    Throw "An unexpected error occurred: $_"
}
```